# MYSQL Select All Rows From Table Based On Last Updated

Tags: mysql

I have a large table on a remote server and want to keep a copy on the local machine in a flat disk file. If I keep a record of a serial number locally read from the first row of the table then can I issue a SELECT command to return all of the rows in the table if the contents of the column at row id=0 <> my locally stored serial number?

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM 1_makes WHERE IF id@0<> local_serial
```

Hope that makes sense

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `1_makes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `allow_global_disc` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_text` text,
  `pack_home_text` text,
  `update_ref` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

So what I want is that the entire tables is returned only if the contents of row with id=0 and update_ref is different to the locally stored value.

If I get results then I know the data has changed so I can save it to a local disk file and update the read update_ref

Looks like this is what I need

I have removed the column update_ref and put the update value in the make column @ id=0

SELECT * FROM 1_makes WHERE (SELECT IF(make <> 'my update number', 1, 0) FROM 1_makes WHERE id = 0)

This works, just wanted to ask what the numbers 1, 0 relate to in IF(make <> 'my update number', 1, 0)

Comment: Whats the question ? Hint : questions normally end with a **?**

Comment: do you know the possible values or range of values of the id? If so, you can construct a select case statement.

Comment: Have you considered running a slave server on the table? It won't allow you to change table engine, but it will probably work a lot more efficiently in keeping the tables in-sync than some script you write (because it uses the binary log to update queries, pretty much as they happen).

Comment: no it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I updated my answer regarding your question about the use of 1 and 0 in the IF statement.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, all understood and a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case would probably be better served by issuing a separate query. The application would first query the value of the row where id=0, and then proceed based on that.

However, you could accomplish this with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM 1_make
WHERE (SELECT IF(update_ref <> :my_number, 1, 0) FROM 1_make WHERE id = 0)
```

Or an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM 1_make t1
INNER JOIN 1_make t2
  ON t2.id = 0 AND t2.update_ref <> :my_number
```

However, if you're just testing to see if there are results, it's best just to return the count rather than return the unused values:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 1_make
WHERE (SELECT IF(update_ref <> :my_number, 1, 0) FROM 1_make WHERE id = 0)
```

Or perhaps even better, use LIMIT to stop after the first row:

```
SELECT id
FROM 1_make
WHERE (SELECT IF(update_ref <> :my_number, 1, 0) FROM 1_make WHERE id = 0)
LIMIT 1
```

Or even better, just use the return value of the IF:

```
SELECT IF(update_ref <> :my_number, 1, 0)
FROM 1_make
WHERE id = 0
```

Even better, why store a value for update_ref for every row? Why not move it to its own table:

```
SELECT IF(update_ref <> :my_number, 1, 0)
FROM my_settings
```

The IF statement return 0, which means false, or 1, which means true.

Finally, if the id is an incremental value, why not just search for rows where the id is larger than the stored last value instead:

```
SELECT id
FROM 1_make
WHERE id > :my_number
LIMIT 1
```

Also, this doesn't account for updates. Only, inserts.

Consider adding a slave server that is replicated from the master server. Then, simply automate backing up the slave server. This is how most backups are done.

Comment: Will the size of the table effect the queery time when using this method SELECT *
FROM 1_make
WHERE (SELECT IF(update_ref <> :my_number, 1, 0) FROM 1_make WHERE id = 0)

Comment: Definitely, with `SELECT *`, you're selecting all columns in all rows.

Comment: what if the SELECT * returns no rows ie. the update_ref is the same as the locally stored one. Will the SQL server scan all of the rows or will it stop when it see's that the update ref is the same?

Comment: @StephenBouffe, That's a good question. If MySQL were smart enough, it would stop. Sorry, I don't know if MySQL is smart enough. Maybe you can determine this through testing.

Comment: OK. created a table with 5 million rows by 3 cols, each col has 1000 characters of data.The server hosting the database is in a data centre and connection is via OpenVPN. The queery takes on average 0.035 seconds. So it must stop after reading the first row.